# Avoid metadata columns in SOAP response

Tags: development, web-services, column, soap, metadata

I searched around the internet (and on this stackexchange site), but didnt find any answer.

I wrote a small C# application that should retrieve some data via the SOAP webservice of a sharepoint server (just a one-way read access) and further process them. So far, it works great, except one small thing: the response contains tons of additional metadata fields:

```
ows_MetaInfo
ows__ModerationStatus
ows__Level
ows_Title
ows_ID
ows_owshiddenversion
ows_UniqueId
ows_FSObjType
ows_Created
ows_FileRef
```

I specified the fields I'm interested in via `ViewFields`, but still all those useless (at least for me) fields are returned, which creates quite an unnecessary overhead.

Is there a way to get rid of these? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Philip...did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SP2007 the best you can do is setting the queryOptions of the GetListItems to:

```
<QueryOptions>
   <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
</QueryOptions>
```

But it'll remove the fields you listed, but only other required fields.
In SP2010 you can set it to

```
<QueryOptions>
   <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
   <ViewFieldsOnly>TRUE</ViewFieldsOnly>
</QueryOptions>
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesnt work. Could the fact that I'm using Sharepoint 2007 be the reason?

Comment: Yes, that was added in 2010

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if theres any possibility to do the same with SP 2007?

Comment: Sorry last comment was wrong, It's ViewFieldsOnly which is new in 2010. IncludeMandatoryColumns is in 2010 but doesn't remove fields which SharePoint thinks are important, but it gets rid of required fields not included in your ViewFields, so if you want minimal response you should include it, but there is no way in SP2007 to get rid of the fields you listed in the question

Comment: Ok, so I guess I have to live with it :). Thank you for the details!

Comment: This doesn't work for crap in SP 2010! I'm still seeing unwanted fields like ows_metainfo after implementing this "solution".